# Python-LDAP authentication on Windows 7

Tags: python, c++, windows, ldap

I would like to install Flask-LDAP to my computer (Windows 7) which has a prerequisite called python-ldap.

I tried to install according to this one:

https://pypi.org/project/python-ldap/3.1.0/

Error message on pip install:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(10) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'vcruntime.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\bin\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Windows SDK 7,10 installed.

Also I am not sure what is going to happen after, because OpenLDAP setup executable asks for serial. I couldn`t find a version which can be installed on Windows. Visual C++ is also installed, I didn`t find anything related to missing vcruntime.h. There is no file like this on my whole machine.

Could someone help me with a guide how to proceed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have no `C++ Compiler for Python`, try to install it in windows:

this is [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266), if your python version is 2.7, you can install `python-ldap` successfully after install vc compiler in windows

Comment: I have Python 3.7. I tried to do it through MingW32 according to this:
https://github.com/valtron/llvm-stuff/wiki/Building-Python-3.4--extension-modules-with-MinGW
Now I have this error in "running build_ext"
    File "c:\python37\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 129, in __init__
      if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
  TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: I have also tried with Python 2.7 with Visual C++ for Python 2.7 installed:
    c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\temp\2\pip-build-dbr9yw\python-ldap\modules\con
stants.h(7) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such fil
e or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsof
t\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: @hkoko try to install it by wheel http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyldap